# With cte, temptable or subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question regarding "subqueries" in SQL. Lets say I want to write a query that will use subqueries. Which of the methods should I use for the best performance?

1)

```
SELECT a.name, a.surname
FROM (
   SELECT tab1.ID, tab1.name, tab2.surname
   FROM tab1
   INNER JOIN tab2 on tab1.ID = tab2.ID
   ) a
WHERE a.name = 'John'
```

2. 

```
with cte1 as (
   SELECT tab1.ID, tab1.name, tab2.surname
   FROM tab1
   INNER JOIN tab2 on tab1.ID = tab2.ID
   )

select cte1.name, cte1.surname
from cte1
where cte1.name = 'John'
```

3. 

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#cte1', 'U') is not null
drop table #cte1;

select tab1.ID, tab1.name, tab2.surname
into #cte1
from tab1
inner join tab2 on tab1.ID = tab2.ID

select #cte1.name, #cte1.surname
from #cte1
where #cte1 = 'John'
```

Usually I'm using 1) method and in case the subquery would be too complicated, I'm using 2).
When it comes to code clarity and simplicity I think 2) is the best.

I suppose `#temptable` in 3) does not use my local RAM and instead it is creating table on a server, therefore it would have the best performance for large tables or if I would write something like

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#cte1', 'U') is not null
drop table #cte1;

select tab1.ID, tab1.name, tab2.surname
into #cte1
from tab1
inner join tab2 on tab1.ID = tab2.ID
;

select #cte1.name, #cte1.surname
from #cte1
where #cte1 = 'John'
;

select #cte1.name, #cte1.surname
from #cte1
where #cte1 = 'Max'
;
```

that is having two separate queries in one window.

Comment: FYI, 1 is a *derived table* not a subquery.

Comment: *"Which of the methods should I use for the best performance?"* Have you raced your horses? What were your findings? A CTE and derived table are, in truth, more or less the same thing; a CTE just has some additional functionality over a derived table.

Comment: As posted you don't really need a sub-query or other and a simple join with where clause will suffice.

Comment: RE: "does not use my local RAM" - no query uses your local RAM - they are all executed on the server. Your local resources are only used to consume the results of the query

Comment: Since the CTE that you described is an instantiated view, in this case method #1 and #2 will result in same plan query plans and hence same performance. on the other hand method #3 is much worse: will incurre in lots of IO for writing in the temp table without any filter and then scan the full temp table to cherry pick the WHERE clause. Think what would happen if if there was 1 row with `tab1.name = 'John'`; tab1 had 100,000,000  rows and all of them join to tab2. you would write 100,000,000 to temp table and then read all of them to pick only one (regardless if you had indexes or not).

Comment: Writing temp tables doesn't cause any IO in modern SQL Server unless you're low on memory.

Comment: The correct answer to "which is faster" when it comes to queries is almost always "it depends", except in very obvious cases (CTE vs. temp table is not). One size does not fit all, as things vary by indexes, table size, row size, disk speed, histogram statistics (present and generated), cardinality estimates, and sometimes phase of the moon. Be wary of drawing any general kind of conclusions; always test with data that's as representative as possible. To a first approximation, write queries in an obvious way that minimizes creating intermediate tables, then start optimizing if it's warranted.

Comment: None of your queries use a "subquery", you either use some form of table expression or a temporary table. Which is best in your scenario... you test each with representative data and find out.

Comment: @Larnu or @ Stu - A note on terminology: it seems like most documentation that I can find define a *derived table* as a *subquery* used in a FROM clause. (Between the lines I expect that to mean as the initial or a joined data source.) Based on that I would say that the two are not distinct, just that a *derived table* **is-a** (particular use of a) *subquery*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75594416/with-cte-temptable-or-subquery/75595484#comment133368616_75594416) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75594416/with-cte-temptable-or-subquery/75595484#comment133368618_75594416)) by [T N](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12637193/t-n):

> Using a #temp table may yield lower performance than the CTE or
> derived table. For the #Temp table, the contents must be gathered and
> stored away (possibly in memory) in advance, while the derived table
> and CTE versions allow that source to be integrated into the execution
> plan of the final query. SQL Server may find ways to optimize the
> combined query in ways not possible with two separate actions. In some
> cases the final query may not use all of the data present in the
> source. In such cases the #temp approach would still retrieve the data
> while the combined query would not.
>
> On the other hand, if you have performance issues and need to tweak
> your queries to optimize results, separate queries may allow you to
> debug and optimize each part individually. It also allows you to
> perhaps to index the temporary table if needed, but those are rare
> scenarios, and indexing the original tables may be a better option.
> Bottom line: The difference in performance may be negligible, in which
> case the decision should be based on readability and maintainability.

And as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75594416/with-cte-temptable-or-subquery/75595484#comment133368824_75594416) by [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert)

> And the correct answer to "which is faster" when it comes to queries
> is almost always "it depends", except in very obvious cases (CTE vs.
> temp table is not). One size does not fit all, as things vary by
> indexes, table size, row size, disk speed, histogram statistics
> (present and generated), cardinality estimates, and sometimes phase of
> the moon. Be wary of drawing any general kind of conclusions; always
> test with data that's as representative as possible. To a first
> approximation, write queries in an obvious way that minimizes creating
> intermediate tables, then start optimizing if it's warranted.